# Set Session Time Limit for Password Protected Posts

Tags: pages, cache, password, session

I have made a series of posts and pages password protected on my website using the built-in Visibility setting. They all use the same password, so the user can view all of them after entering the password once.

**The problem:** I need the session to time out after an hour. I have tried using this code in my functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'post_pw_sess_expire' );
    function post_pw_sess_expire() {
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] ) )
    // Setting a time of 0 in setcookie() forces the cookie to expire with the session
    setcookie('wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, '', 0, COOKIEPATH);
}
```

It successfully clears the cache, but I would like to extend the time rather than expiring the session immediately. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think what you need is the [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) manual.

Comment: Thank you! I have not used setcookie() before, but I will give it a try.

Comment: WoW. Why do you say that you have not use `setcookie()` before if you are using `setcookie()`it the code you posted.

Comment: Fair point. That is a code snippet copied from another source. It does not appear to be working as I would like, and I am unfamiliar with the setcookie() function and how to manipulate it. Thank you for the link to the manual. Hopefully that will help!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is when you execute this code

```
setcookie('wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, '', 0, COOKIEPATH);
```

It will reset your post password cookie to blank '', so it just work once To solve this you need to assign the original cookie and extend the timeout, like this

```
setcookie('wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH], time() + 60 * 5, COOKIEPATH);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

You just need to hook into the filter like this and replace `0` with a time calculation, like `time() + 60`

```
function set_cookie_expire () {
    echo 0;
}
add_filter('post_password_expires', 'set_cookie_expire');
```